# Do disjunctive sequences have an extension to countable subsequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

A sequence is called [disjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence) if it contains all sequences within it.  More specifically, a sequence is disjunctive in base $b$ if it contains all *finite* sequences (or base $b$ words) within its base $b$ representation.

This is an interesting property, and it makes me wonder.  **Do there exist sequences that contain all possible *countably infinite* sequences?  If so, what are they called?**

---

I can't think of a reason they shouldn't exist, but maybe there's a good reason that I'm just overlooking.  My first concern was that a sequence containing infinitely many infinite subsequences might already be impossible.  But a trivial example shows it's possible:

Consider the set of all countable sequences on the natural numbers which are strictly monotonically increasing.  Call it $\mathcal{S}$.

Define $s_o = (1, 2, ...)$ - the sequence which simply enumerates the natural numbers.  Clearly, every $s \in \mathcal{S}$ is a subsequence of $s_o$.

$$
\forall s \in \mathcal{S}  ,  s \subseteq s_o
$$

And $\mathcal{S}$ contains infinitely many sequences.  (Though I'm not sure if $\mathcal{S}$ is countable or not.)  So unless I've made a mistake, it's possible for a single countable sequence to contain infinitely many countable subsequences.

But that's essentially a toy problem - I'm a long way off from answering my question and I'm not even sure what terms to search for related results.

Comment: The answer is no, since there are uncountably many such sequences.

Comment: Ah, and there can be no countable sequence containing uncountably many elements, let alone uncountably many subsequences.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Though I wonder, what if one relaxed the conventional definition of "sequence" to include uncountably many elements?  (Not trying to be contrarian, just really curious.)  To use the language of [this answerer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/724527/426612), "_The only defining property of a sequence is that it is a function from a well-ordered domain, so the notion of "the next term" makes sense. There are uncountable well-ordered sets, and so we can talk about longer sequences, uncountably long sequences._"

Comment: The answer is yes. Note that there is an obvious bijection between the set of countable sequences and $\mathbb R$, so consider the set of elements of the form $(r,i)$, where $r$ is the sequence label from $\mathbb R$, and $i$ is the element of the sequence in $\mathbb N$. The dictionary ordering on this set is a well-order (assuming some well-order on $\mathbb R$, of course. AC always find its way into well-order based questions).